# Overrule bootstrap media query does not work

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I'm trying to overrule a css rule of Bootstrap 3..

My custom css:

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 50px;

}
```

But it wont work..

When I remove the media query, it works, but then it's not responsive anymore...

What's going wrong? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@media (min-width: 768px)  {` <<-- You're missing the opening curly bracket

Comment: Please provide a bit more codes so we can help you debug the responsive issue too

Comment: Andrew was right... Saw to much code today I guess.. Stupid that I did'nt saw this.. Can only accept answer in 10 minutes.. Will do this certainly :)

Comment: the responsive issue is fixed because I use the media query properly now. :).